# Samba share error (this location could not be displayed. You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of "<username> on <local-ip>")

Tags: linux, samba

I have a Fedora 39 home server freshly set up. It appears that when I specifically set the `/home` partition separate from the `/` partition, I receive the samba error specified in the title when trying to access my home folder (with the appropriate user of course). Thanks in advance, have a good day!

this is the output of lsblk

```
NAME                                          MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sda                                             8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk  
├─sda1                                          8:1    0  600M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2                                          8:2    0    1G  0 part  /boot
└─sda3                                          8:3    0  1.8T  0 part  
  └─luks-bed4a235-ac5a-48d0-9928-d3dfae43055e 253:0    0  1.8T  0 crypt 
    ├─fedora-01                               253:1    0   15G  0 lvm   /
    ├─fedora-00                               253:2    0  5.6G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    └─fedora-02                               253:3    0  1.8T  0 lvm   /home
sr0                                            11:0    1 1024M  0 rom   
zram0                                         252:0    0  5.7G  0 disk  [SWAP]
```

Comment: show us the smb.conf for your HOMES share, and the directory permissions on /home and the /home/<user>/ dir

Comment: So this is the samba config: https://pastebin.com/UeTtm42z and the /home/<user> are theese drwx------. 2 gabriel gabriel 83 Jan 19 20:03 /home/gabriel

Comment: I'm assuming you are trying to use the share 'Gabriel'. try adding a 'valid users' line that allows the appropriate users. per https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html 'force users' relies on 'valid users' and (by ommission) implies that 'guest ok' may not be sufficient to make it work. just a guess.

Comment: I would preferably like to use the home folder (although adding valid users line still did not fix anything). I noticed that this issue is only apparent when having the home partition separate from the root, hence I specified this in my post (I know it is strange but I don't know...)

Comment: I forgot to add/update the selinux permissions (fedora server enforces selinux by default)(first time I migrated the home partition from root to a separate one and didn't think I needed to update anything, apparently I did).